# Mapping JSONs library

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I have an object (for example a ball) which has specific data members and functions which are being used in my project but I am also getting other balls from different servers which are publishing the ball object but in different hierarchy for example:

```
class Ball {
  int size;
  string color;
}
```

So an instance of this class in JSON would be for example:

```
{ ball: {
size: 3,
color: red
}}
```

But the problem is when I'm getting a different hierarchy of ball but the logic is still the same, for example I'm getting from other server a Boll which has these data members:

```
Class Boll{
int mass;
View color;
}

Class View {
string color;
}
```

So an instance of the boll class in JSON would be for example:

```
{ Boll: {
mass: 3,
view: {
 color: red
}}
```

So we can say that these two classes are very similar to each other.

When I tried to solve this problem I made a `Map<string, string>` and put every attribute from my class with the other class but when I came up with complex objects (such as view for example) I couldn't come up with an idea to how to solve this problem and in my project I am handling with some serious objects so I can't use my old solution anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a single Ball object in your Angular code:

```
class Ball {
mass: Number;
color: string;
}
```

And from each different request since you know the format map of the services you map in each request to your object like this

```
public getBallsFromServerA(): Observable<Ball[]> {
 return this.http.get('ballUrlA')
   .map(response => { let balls: Ball[] = response.json()
   .map(val => { return { mass: val.size, color: val.view.color};});
 return balls;
 })
```

Comment: My objects are far more complicated than the examples I wrote here, the object that I'm using has more than 300 different and changing values , so I can't use your solution :S

Comment: how else are you going to do it ?

Comment: I thought maybe there will be a library that does that or a "best-practice" way to do this...